# AI and Game physics

Tags: python, pytorch, pygame, artificial-intelligence, game-physics

When I run my test, it works completely fine with one update. However, when I make my AI do the inputs, the cube just drops off the screen, with the player's position rapidly increasing positively, and the velocity and y for the player's position increasing negatively.  And I’m stuck because I wouldn’t think it’s the collision with the floor where it falls out cause the test run works. Maybe it’s the rapid input of the AI? Here is the GitHub for the project [physics-ai-game](https://github.com/hprymak07/physics-ai-game).

- My current game file:

```
import pygame
from math import dist

pygame.init()
w, h = 1250, 720

class Direction:
    @staticmethod
    def update(left=0, right=0, jump=0):
        return left, right, jump

class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 10, 10)
        self.vel_x = 0
        self.vel_y = 0
        self.gravity = 0.2
        self.ground = False
        self.collision_tol = 5

    def update_velo(self, left, right, jump):
        self.vel_x = 300 if right == 1 else 0 if left == 1 else 0
        self.vel_y += self.gravity
        self.vel_y = -10 if jump == 1 else self.vel_y
        print("Velocity X:", self.vel_x)
        print("Velocity Y:", self.vel_y)

    def move(self):
        self.rect.x += self.vel_x
        self.rect.y += self.vel_y
        print("Player Position:", self.rect.x, self.rect.y)

    def collisions(self, objects, walls):

        for object in objects:
            if self.rect.colliderect(object):
                print("Collision detected with object:", object)
                if abs(self.rect.right - object.left) <= self.collision_tol:
                    self.rect.right = object.left
                    self.ground = True
                elif abs(self.rect.left - object.right) <= self.collision_tol:
                    self.rect.left = object.right
                    self.ground = True
                elif self.rect.bottom >= object.top:
                    self.rect.bottom = object.top
                    self.ground = True
                    self.vel_y = 0
                elif self.rect.top <= object.bottom:
                    self.rect.top = object.bottom
                    self.ground = False
                else:
                    self.ground = False
        
        for wall in walls:
            if self.rect.colliderect(wall):
                print("Collision detected with wall:", wall)
                if self.vel_x > 0:
                    self.rect.right = wall.left
                elif self.vel_x < 0:
                    self.rect.left = wall.right

                if self.vel_y > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = wall.top
                    self.vel_y = 0
                    self.ground = True
                    
                elif self.vel_y < 0:
                    self.rect.top = wall.bottom
                    self.vel_y = 0

    def update(self, left, right, jump, objects, walls):
        self.update_velo(left, right, jump)
        self.move()
        self.collisions(objects, walls)
        print("Player position:", self.rect.x, self.rect.y)

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.display = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
        pygame.display.set_caption("AI Game")
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.endpt = pygame.Rect(1200, h - 250, 20, 20)
        self.floor = pygame.Rect(0, h - 20, w, 200)
        self.left_wall = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 20, h)
        self.right_wall = pygame.Rect(w - 20, 0, 20, h)
        self.objects_for_lvl = [
            pygame.Rect(100, h - 100, 100, 80),
            pygame.Rect(250, h - 140, 100, 25),
            pygame.Rect(400, h - 170, 100, 25),
            pygame.Rect(535, h - 170, 75, 25),
            pygame.Rect(735, h - 170, 75, 25),
            pygame.Rect(900, h - 200, 150, 25),
            pygame.Rect(1150, h - 230, 200, 25)
        ]

        self.player = Player(30, 600)
        self.running = True
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.score = 0
        self.frame_iteration = 0

    def step(self, action):
        self.frame_iteration += 1

        for ev in pygame.event.get():
            if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        left, right, jump = action
        self.player.update(left, right, jump, self.objects_for_lvl, [self.floor, self.left_wall, self.right_wall])

        reward, game_over = self.calculate_score()

        self._update()

        return reward, game_over, self.score

    def calculate_score(self):
        reward = 0
        game_over = False

        if self.player.rect.colliderect(self.endpt):
            reward += 10
        elif self.player.rect.colliderect(self.floor):
            reward -= 5

        self.score += reward
        game_over = self.player.rect.colliderect(self.left_wall) or self.player.rect.colliderect(self.right_wall)

        return reward, game_over

    def _update(self):    
        self.display.fill('white')  

        for obj in self.objects_for_lvl:  
            pygame.draw.rect(self.display, (128, 128, 128), obj)

        pygame.draw.rect(self.display, (128, 128, 128), self.floor)  
        pygame.draw.rect(self.display, (128, 128, 128), self.left_wall)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.display, (128, 128, 128), self.right_wall)
    
        pygame.draw.rect(self.display, (255, 0, 0), self.player.rect)  # Draw player object
        pygame.draw.rect(self.display, (0, 255, 0), self.endpt)  

        pygame.display.update()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = Game()
    while game.running:
        action = Direction.update(1, 0, 0) # move left once 
        print("Action:", action)
        reward, game_over, score = game.step(action)
        if game_over:
            print("Game Over")
            game.running = False
```

Comment: Apologies but this is a different question. I don’t know if you read either post. But the first referred to a horizontal velocity redundancy. I’ve not only changed the code I’ve changed the question to what I think is a multiple input problem or a problem with the y velocity. I deleted the other post as-well before I made this one for this exact reason. 

But I again apologize for inconveniencing you all my intention is not to abuse the system. I thought It would be more beneficial to start a fresh post, delete the old one, and reassign the problem for clarity.